# Onsen splitView callback

Tags: onsen-ui

I'm using onsen-ui **splitView**. 
Can I do *callback* after mainpage changed?

This is my code:

```
<ons-list-item 
    modifier="chevron"
    ng-click="ons.splitView.toggle(); ons.splitView.setMainPage('report.html');"
    class="label-sm font-sm"
    onclick="report()">
    <i class="fa fa-bar-chart fa-lg" style="color: #666"></i>
    &nbsp; Report
</ons-list-item>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's a `presplit` and a `postsplit` event. There are also `precollapse` and `postcollapse` events. You can use them to attach callbacks.

```
ons.splitView.on('postsplit', function(e) {
  console.log(e);
});
```

The event object has the following properties:

```
e.splitView // Splitview object
e.width // Window width
e.orientation // "landscape" or "portrait"
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: You can use the `ons.ready(fn)` callback, if you use that it will run after OnsenUI is loaded.

Comment: i have put this on my javasript file
`ons.splitView.on('postsplit', function (e) {
    alert("X");
});`
but not working

Comment: Oh, and you get no error that ons.splitView isn't defined?

Comment: That means the `ons.splitView` isn't defined. Did you use the `var="variableName"` on the split view element?

Comment: No, there is not any var in my element

Comment: Please try something like `<ons-split-view var="app.splitView" ...` and use that variable instead. It will attach to `window` so you'll get `window.app.splitView`.

Comment: ok, still error if i put outside `$(document).ready()` but not working if i put inside there, where should i put this code?